# Autocomplete TextView with dynamic value in dialog

Tags: android, autocomplete, dialog, spinner, android-alertdialog

I am using an autocomplete textview which retrieves data from server dynamically.This autocomplete textview is inside a custom dialog box.Everything is working fine but the only problem is that when i try to retrieve the selected autocomplete value it is giving me null value.

Here are my declarations in fragment -

```
AutoCompleteTextView sp_city;
ArrayAdapter<GetMyCityAdapter> spinneradapter;

    List<GetMyCityAdapter> getMyCityAdapter1;
    private ArrayList<String> city = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Here is my dialog box code -

```
 btn_searchfreelancerfilter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                // ...Irrelevant code for customizing the buttons and title
                LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.freelancerfilterdialog, null);
                dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
                dialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                dialogBuilder.setTitle("Search Freelancer");
                sp_city.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        selectedcityvalue = spinneradapter.getItem(i).getCity_name();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                    }
                });



                sp_city = (AutoCompleteTextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.sp_sf_city);
                      loadCity();

                dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Search", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        LoadFilteredData(selectedcityvalue);

                    }
                });
                final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();

            }
        });
```

Here is my `loadCity` method code -

```
  private void loadCity() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_CITY, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response_city) {
                showJSONCITY(response_city);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.d("Error", "" + error);
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        int socketTimeout = 30000;
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
    private void showJSONCITY(String response_city) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response_city);
            JSONArray data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = data.getJSONObject(i);
                GetMyCityAdapter getMyCityAdapter2 = new GetMyCityAdapter("0", "select_type");
                getMyCityAdapter2.setCity_id(jsonObject1.getString("c_id"));
                getMyCityAdapter2.setCity_name(jsonObject1.getString("c_name"));
                getMyCityAdapter1.add(getMyCityAdapter2);
                city.add(jsonObject1.getString("c_name"));
            }

            ArrayList<GetMyCityAdapter> citylist = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < city.size(); i++) {
                citylist.add(new GetMyCityAdapter(getMyCityAdapter1.get(i).getCity_id(), getMyCityAdapter1.get(i).getCity_name()));
            }
            spinneradapter = new ArrayAdapter<GetMyCityAdapter>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, citylist);
            sp_city.setAdapter(spinneradapter);
            sp_city.setThreshold(1);
            sp_city.setSelection(0);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have successfully retrieved the data .Autocomplete has been populated with the data from server.It is just not being retrieved on setitemclicklistener.
There is no error but it is giving null values on retrieving the selected values.

Comment: You successfully retrieved data from the server isn't? It's just that the data is not being passed in the autoComplete?

Comment: please, print the raw response to view whether the response contains the data do you want or not

Comment: try to fetch the selected value from your cityList instead of adapter

Comment: i have successfully retrieved the data .Autocomplete has been populated with the data from server.It is just not being retrieved on setitemclicklistener @FreelancsAndroidLovesyou

Comment: @AgiMaulana it does get the response .but i am not able to get the selected value

Comment: So the selectedcityvalue is giving you a null value?

Comment: @FreelancsAndroidLovesyou yes..

Answer (score 0):

You should first call your

> loadCity();

Just like :

```
 sp_city = (AutoCompleteTextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.sp_sf_city);
                  loadCity();

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.freelancerfilterdialog, null);
            dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
            dialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
            dialogBuilder.setTitle("Search Freelancer");
            sp_city.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    selectedcityvalue = spinneradapter.getItem(i).getCity_name();
                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }
            });
```

In this way you need to call first all of your data from the Server before setting an adapter to your AutoCompleteTextView.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference ...this error comes when i call load city in oncreate of fragment and when i call loadcity() first in dialog ,nothing happens .Data is loaded but setonclicklistener is not getting called